# Rust string capacity lower than string lenght

Tags: debugging, memory

[According to RUST documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html#ways-variables-and-data-interact-move), strings are stored this way :

[image]

This is a statement I can verify while reversing rust binaries.
The thing is that when I am reversing rust binaries, I likely encounter cases where capacity is lower than length of the string, eg :

```
[stack]:00007FFC8BE97218 str_ABCED dq offset ABCED               ; DATA XREF: XX
[stack]:00007FFC8BE97218                                         ; (len=10) ABCEDFGHIJ
[stack]:00007FFC8BE97220 dq 28h                                  ; String len: 40
[stack]:00007FFC8BE97228 cap_ABCED dq 25h                        ; String 'capacity'
```

How is such a thing possible? Do any resource exists explaining rust internals?

Comment: If you check the acrual string pointer, how much space is reserved there?

Comment: @usr2564301 not sure to understand what you mean, the actual string is 40 bytes long, as stated by the "string len" (0x00007FFC8BE97220) in memory

Comment: Can you paste the code you used to create this string because I am not able to reproduce this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you considered the possibility that it might be using the **[str](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html)**
instead of **[String](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html)** which only has length and no capacity and
you are looking at a bogus third value ?

```
:\>cat main.rs
fn main() {
        let s1 = String::from("Hello, std::world!");
    println!("{}",s1);
        println!("{} {}",s1.capacity() , s1.len());
        let s2 = "Hello, std::world!o";
    println!("{}",s2);
        println!("{} {}",s2.capacity() , s2.len());
}
:\>cargo build
   Compiling hello_world v0.1.0 
error[E0599]: no method named `capacity` found for reference `&str` in the current scope
 --> main.rs:7:22
  |
7 |     println!("{} {}",s2.capacity() , s2.len());
  |                         ^^^^^^^^ method not found in `&str`
```

like shown below for the first string

```
0:000> dv /v 
00000064`f0cff920              s2 = struct str*
00000064`f0cff8c0              s1 = "Hello, std::world!"
0:000> dpa 00000064`f0cff920 l3
00000064`f0cff920  00007ff6`65cf2638 "Hello, std::world!o"
00000064`f0cff928  00000000`00000013
00000064`f0cff930  00000000`00000010  <<<<<<<  bogus garbage 
0:000> dpa 00000064`f0cff8c0 l3
00000064`f0cff8c0  00000174`116191f0 "Hello, std::world!.............................."
00000064`f0cff8c8  00000000`00000012
00000064`f0cff8d0  00000000`00000012  <<<<<<<<<<<<< correct
```

Comment: This is probably it, missed that details in the doc ! Thanks !